# Globo pedidos auto refresh

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, sql

Estoy con el back de una web que es tienda, y estoy preparando los típicos globos que están encima del carrito, para notificarte cuantos pedidos hay nuevos en la web, comprobandolos en la BD.

**Script con el que compruebo y imprimo cada 3000**

```
<script>
 (function($) {
 var fnConsulta = function(){
 $.ajax({
 url : 'totalpedidos.php', // URL donde se encuentra el archivo php
 type : 'POST', // Puede ser GET
 success : function( resp ){ // Función que procesará la respuesta (JSON)
 // Aquí ya puedo mostrar los globos con la respuesta
 $( "#respuestaTotalPedidos" ).html( resp );
 },
  error: function(){
  alert( 'Ocurrió un error' );
 }
 });
 };
 fnConsulta();
  //Ahora va el código del timer, llamará al php cada minuto
  timerConsulta = setInterval(function(){
 fnConsulta();
 }, 3000);
 })(jQuery);
</script>
```

**En la misma página tengo un span con id=#respuestaTotalPedidos**

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown cuenta" style="margin: 5px 5px 0 0 !important;">
  <i class="icon-basket"></i><span id="respuestaTotalPedidos" class="">&nbsp;</span>                    
</li>
```

**Por otro lado el query para comprobar en la BD**

```
<?php 
  $globos = $mysqli->query("SELECT count(*) as total from pedidos WHERE status=0");
   while($data = $globos->fetch_array()== 0){
   echo $data['total'] ? $data['total'] : 0  ;
}
?>
```

Lo que sucede es que no me muestra nada el globo, y parece que el refresco funciona bien, porque en el inspector carga la query cada 3 seg.

Comment: Tengo la impresión de que tu problema esta en esta linea `while($data = $globos->fetch_array() == 0){` Estas asignando un booleano a $data.

Comment: @JDev podría ser, pero no consigo localizar el error

Comment: sobraba el `==0` no se muy bien que hacia ahí

Comment: Una pregunta @JDev hay alguna forma que notifique con sonido también?

Comment: Supongo que si, pero no se como se haría.

Comment: no le quites el error que tenias a la pregunta original, si no no se comprende que pasaba, el resultado debe ir en la zona de respuestas

Comment: Listo! ya lo volvi a cambiar, gracias @JDev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado quitando el ==0

```
<?php 
 $globos = $mysqli->query("SELECT count(*) as total from pedidos WHERE status=0");
 while($data = $globos->fetch_array()){
 echo $data['total'] ? $data['total'] : 0  ;
}
?>
```